# Complex SQL query with nodes-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have a problem running the following SQL query to my MySQL database with nodeJS and the node-mysql packe which is added with npm.

```
INSERT INTO locations (locationID,name,latitude,longitude)
SELECT '214777725','Bryans Road,
Maryland','38.628055556','-77.081666667'
FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM locations WHERE locationID = '214777725')
```

I've tried the following code:

```
var arrValues = [ -12.9747, -38.4767, 213287181, 'Salvador, Brazil' ];
var arrNames = [ 'latitude', 'longitude', 'locationID', 'name' ];
var locationID = "214777725";
if(imageData["locationID"] != null) {
    var query = "INSERT INTO locations ? ";
    query = query + " SELECT (?)";
    query = query + " FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS";
    query = query + " (SELECT * FROM locations WHERE locationID = ?)";
    console.log(query);
    connection.query(query, [arrNames,arrValues,locationID], function(err,res)
    {
      if(err)
      {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Insert-Success: " +id);
      }
    });
}
```

Running this the console writes following error:

```
{
    code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
    errno: 1064,
    sqlState: '42000',
    index: 0 
}
```

I hope somebody can help.

Comment: why not just make `locationID` a primary key? then any insert which tries to re-use that key will simply fail. and note that placeholders can represent only SINGLE values. you can't use them to replace multiple fields. they're a 1:1 mapping, not 1:n or n:1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't set the locationID as primary key because it's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the .toString(); function on your arrays.

```
connection.query(query, [arrNames.toString(),arrValues.toString(),locationID], function(err,res)
{ ...
```

Comment: It works now. I'm creating the whole query as a string with the values and then I'm running this query without any parameters. Thank you.